Javascript add days to a date
I need to visualize a div containing all 30 days after the current one. But when javascript add a day after 1 december 2024 the result is 1 january 2025.
This is the code


var ldate = new Date();
var shdate = new Date(); 
    
function updCalen(){
  document.getElementById('settim').innerHTML = ""
  var vday  = 0 ;
  for (i= 0; i < 30; i++) {
    shdate.setDate(ldate.getDate() +  i );
    document.getElementById('settim').innerHTML += shdate + '<BR>' ;        
  }
}
    
updCalen()
<div id="settim" style="width:600px; height:400px; padding:3px; border: #099 thin solid; overflow:scroll"></div>



I'm struggling with this problem but I can't find how to solve it!

Your code doesn't run. getDate() is not defined, nor is shdate. Are you familiar with using your debugger?

getDate() is a javascript function, shdate is declared in an other point of the code. After the 1 Dec 2024 javascript add a month instead of a day

But what date are you getting the date from? Here is the documentation for getDate. And how are we supposed to run your code if you haven't defined all the relevant variables for us? Please [edit] your code to include a [mre].

We need a [mcve] and getDate is a method of the Date object which you didn't define. var ldate = new getDate()  returns Uncaught ReferenceError: getDate is not defined

code updated ready to run

Your problem is with using get/setDate, which sets the day of the month. A better way to solve this problem is to use get/setTime


document.querySelector('input').valueAsDate = new Date();
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener( "click", () => {
  let dt = new Date(document.querySelector("Input").value);
  console.log(dt);
  let time = dt.getTime();
  time = time + 30 * 24 /*hours*/ * 60 /* minutes */ * 60 /* seconds */ * 1000 /* ms */
  let newDt = new Date(time);
  console.log(newDt);
});
<input type="date" />
<button>Test</button>




Thank you ! getTime works fine for what I need. I still can't understand why the previous code cause that problem. Thank you !!!

@angeloalamia The problem in your code is your logic... You don't need ldate and should just change shdate.setDate(ldate.getDate() + i ); to shdate.setDate(shdate.getDate() + 1); leave the rest as is and it will work just fine.

@angeloalamia In your code you're always retrieving the day from ldate that is not changing at all in your loop and you're using it to update shdate adding the value of i. Lets say today is the 15th. When your i reaches 17 then shdate will be updated with 15 from ldate + 17 from i that equals 32. This causes the shdate to skip a month. Then, when i becomes 18, you're updating shdate again with 15 from ldate + 18 from i that equals 33. This causes the shdate to skip another month and some days... Did you get where this is going? So, this is the problem.

@angeloalamia var shdate = new Date(); function updCalen(){ for (i= 0; i < 30; i++){ shdate.setDate(shdate.getDate() + 1); console.log(String(shdate)); } } updCalen();
If you run this at your console it should work as you expected.

Re "A better way to solve this problem is to use get/setTime". No it isn't. Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, adding 24 hours can advance the date by two days or zero depending on the start date and time. The best way (i.e. most reliable and robust) is to just add 1 to the date. See How can I add 1 day to current date?.

function updCalen(date, days) {
  const result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}

var today = new Date();
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  const newDate = updCalen(today, i);
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
